# webkit view is getting dismissed after copy link action in swift 3

Tags: ios, webkit, presentviewcontroller

I am using webkit to load webpage on separate ViewController which I present to my existing ViewController. After some action I am geting a link. When I long press the link I get following options

[image]

When I click on copy, my presented ViewController is getting dismissed. This happens on device with iOS 11.2.2. But this is not happening when I am using device with iOS 10.3.2. I am using Xcode 8.3.2. To test on device 11.2.2 I have used TestFlight build.

Do anyone know why is this happening?